# Why does an open map send generic points to generic point?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, open-map

I might miss the forest for the trees but:

The situation is (too) special, I think. Nevertheless I'll describe it: I have an open morphism $X\to Y$ of schemes (morphism is locally of finite type). The schemes are locally Noetherian and $Y$ is irreducible with generic point $\eta$. Why (due to the openness of $f$) do we have $f(\xi)=\eta$ for any generic point of $X$?

The more general question (as I do think we don't need the assertions above): Why does an open continuous map into an irreducible space send generic points of the domain to the generic point of the target space?

Thank you!!

Comment: By "a generic point of $X$" do you mean a generic point of an irreducible component of $X$?  You will need some hypotheses on $X$ for this to make sense in your general question...

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant generic point of some irreducible component. Thx.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that by "generic point of $X$" you mean "generic point of an irreducible component of $X$", this is true for any locally Noetherian space $X$.  First, note that we may assume $X$ is irreducible: let $U$ be a Noetherian open set containing $\xi$, and then restrict $f$ to the complement in $U$ of all of the irreducible components of $U$ except the closure of $\xi$ (this complement is still open since there are only finitely many such components, by Noetherianness).

Now if $X$ is irreducible, every point in $X$ is in the closure of $\{\xi\}$.  If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, that means every point in $f(X)$ is in the closure of $\{f(\xi)\}$.  If $f$ is also an open map, this means that the closure of $\{f(\xi)\}$ has nonempty interior.  If $Y$ is irreducible, this means the closure of $\{f(\xi)\}$ must be all of $Y$, since every nonempty open set is dense in $Y$.  Thus $f(\xi)$ must be the generic point of $Y$.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks a lot for your answer. I actually had (a little bit more general) the very same proof, but I thought there could be some one-line-argument. Nevertheless I am very thankful for your answer.

Comment: Well, the one-line condensation would be "Since $\overline{\{\xi\}}$ has nonempty interior, $\overline{\{f(\xi)\}}$ must have nonempty interior as well, so $f(\xi)=\eta$".  But that's glossing over a lot of details that may not be obvious.

Comment: there you are very right! Thx